# PostgreSQL ERROR: 42P01: relation "public.{tableName}" does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

PostgreSQL version:
PostgreSQL 10.17 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9), 64-bit

Running as RDS db in AWS cloud.

Problem:
I no longer see the "public" schema under the default postgres database on the server. This schema was being used to host some our data. The schema was not dropped by anyone. Would there any other possibility of it being dropped or made unavailable in the server?

I can't think of any reason how a schema would just disappear without anyone explicitly dropping it from the database.

Could there be any permission changes that could be causing the public schema to not show up for my logged in user even though I'm the admin user?

If the schema is truly gone, then I need to find a way to restore/recover the missing data. Please let me know if there are any steps that I could take in that regards as well.

Comment: The error is `relation "public.{tableName}" does not exist` . This does not necessarily mean the schema is missing. It could mean: 1) The [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) has been changed. 2) The `tableName` is mixed or upper case and has not been double quoted to preserve case. I don't use `RDS` but can you use `psql` to connect to database and do `\dn` to get list of schemas?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, the list of schemas after running \dn in psql doesn't show the public schema anymore.

Comment: Then you have a problem. Either someone(thing) dropped the schema or you are connected to the wrong database. I don't use or want to use RDS so I can't be of much help here. I will point you at [RDS backup](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/features/backup/). You might reach out to AWS support for further assistance.

Comment: In addition looking at the Postgres logs may help establish the when and who?